# npm install command never ending on Angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I work on an Angular 2 project and sometimes when I execute the npm install command, it's never ending. I can see a progress bar, once the bar is full a new npm install command is displayed on the command console, a new progress bar and so on.

For the moment I remove all the module under node_modules and restart the npm install from scratch but it is not acceptable.

Is this problem wellknown? Is there a solution?

Comment: `npm cache clean`, `npm i`. But I'd suggest to use yarn: `npm i -g yarn`, then `yarn`

Comment: npm cache clean did not solved my problem.

Comment: we don't use yarn, npm with nexus 3 repository

Comment: without the exact errors text I can't say more, maybe the problem in nexus, but I'm not familiar with it. yarn just released yesterday, nobody use it, but you can give him a try

Comment: where can I see logs ? there is no npmdebug.log in the project root

Comment: what is your git version

Comment: Try appending --verbose to your npm install command. It will give you more details on the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Had that issue because of my connection before. Might be the same for you. Try disabling firewall. Or even try using some other internet connection outside a corporate or protected one.